# Set operations (complement and difference)

Tags: c#, set, set-operations

How can I make set complement and set difference in C# **without using any collections and Linq?**

We have two arrays:

```
int [] arr1 = new int { 1, 2, 3, 4};
int[] arr2 = new int {3,4,5,6,7,8};
```

Complement must be: `arr3 {5,6,7,8}` and the difference must be: `arr4 {1,2}`.

I've tried adding one set to another and then finding duplicates, but couldn't make it.

```
int numDups = 0, prevIndex = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    bool foundDup = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        if (array[i] == array[j])
        {
            foundDup = true;
            numDups++; // Increment means Count for Duplicate found in array.
            break;
        }                    
    }

    if (foundDup == false)
    {
        array[prevIndex] = array[i];
        prevIndex++;
    }
}

// Just Duplicate records replce by zero.
for (int k = 1; k <= numDups; k++)
{               
    array[array.Length - k] = '\0';             
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two lists, one for complement and other for difference, iterate array A and check which are contained in B and which not and vice-versa, iterate B and check which ones exists in A.

UPDATE: removed lists, used only arrays and no LINQ.

```
int[] arr1 = new int[]{ 1,2,3,4 };
int[] arr2 = new int[]{ 3,4,5,6,7,8 };

//We allocate the max possible size for each array, just for sanity
int[] arr3 = new int[arr1.Length + arr2.Length];
int[] arr4 = new int[arr1.Length + arr2.Length];

int difIndex = 0;
int compIndex = 0;

//Compute difference 
foreach(int i in arr1)
{
    bool found = false;
    foreach(int i2 in arr2)
    {
        if(i == i2)
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!found)
        arr4[difIndex++] = i;
}

//Compute complement
foreach(int i in arr2)
{
    bool found = false;
    foreach(int i2 in arr1)
    {
        if(i == i2)
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!found)
        arr3[compIndex++] = i;
}

//Remove unused items from array
Array.Resize(ref arr3, compIndex);
Array.Resize(ref arr4, difIndex);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can use neither System.Collections.Generic nor System.Collections.Generic.List. Linq is also prohibited((( That's the task

Comment: @InfernalDiablo Updated

Answer (score 0):

Given that premise, we could create the function `getComplement` like so:

```
int[][] getComplement(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    
    int[] complement = {};
    int[] difference = {};

    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
    {
        bool isDupe = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < arr2.Length; j++) {
            if (arr1[i] == arr2[j] && !isDupe) {
                Array.Resize(ref complement, complement.Length + 1);
                complement[complement.GetUpperBound(0)] = arr2[j];
                isDupe = true;
            }
        }
        if (!isDupe) {
            Array.Resize(ref difference, difference.Length + 1);
            difference[difference.GetUpperBound(0)] = arr1[i];
        }
    }
    
    return new[] { complement, difference };
}
```

and then apply it upon our 2 existing arrays to get the desired results:

```
int [] arr1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int[] arr2 = new int[] { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
int[][] complementArr = getComplement(arr1, arr2);
int[][] differenceArr = getComplement(arr2, complementArr[0]);
int[] arr3 = differenceArr[1];
int[] arr4 = complementArr[1];
```

You can see [a working demo here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JuIQXT).

Answer (score -2):

The difference between collections `A` and `B` are all elements in `A` that are not in `B`. The compliment between those collections are all elements in `B` that are not in `A`. These are mirror definitions, so you really only need to write a method for difference and then have the compliment method call the difference method with the input parameters reversed.

(Well, strictly speaking, the compliment is all elements *anywhere* that are not in `A`, but that distinction is irrelevant here.)

```cs
// Get an array of all elements in b that are not in a
// This is identical to calling GetDifference with the inputs reversed so lets just do that
int[] GetCompliment(int[] a, int[] b) { return GetDifference(b, a); }

// Get an array of all elements in a that are not in b
int[] GetDifference(int[] a, int[] b) 
{
    // Create the buffer array at the worst-case length which is the length
    // of a (where none of the elements in a are in b)
    int[] c = new int[a.Length];

    // Track how many elements we are actually ending up with
    int length = 0;

    // Loop through every element in a
    foreach (var ax in a)
    {
        bool found = false;
        // Loop through every element in b to see if it exists in a
        foreach (var bx in b)
        {
            if (ax == bx)
            {
                // If the element was found in b, there's no reason to keep looping
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Only save the element if it was not found in b
        if (!found)
        {
            c[length] = ax;
            length++;
        }
    }

    // Create the result array using the length of actual elements found
    int[] result = new int[length];

    // Copy the relevant slice of the buffer array into the result array
    Array.Copy(c, result, length);

    // Return the result array
    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```cs
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int[] b = { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
int[] c = GetDifference(a, b);
        
foreach(var cx in c)
{
    Console.Write(cx + ", ");   
}
        
Console.WriteLine();
int[] d = GetCompliment(a, b);
        
foreach(var dx in d)
{
    Console.Write(dx + ", ");   
}

// Output:
// 1, 2, 
// 5, 6, 7, 8
```

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/i5q3jj)